# Rewrite PHP parameters for RoR in nginx

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting, nginx, routes

I have a website which used to be written in PHP and I re-wrote using Rails. It's essentially a blog platform consisting of posts. I am still getting requests from Google using the old URL scheme. They are rendering the index page, but they should be showing the specific posts referenced. For example:

http://domain.com/posts?page=5&postID=6433 (renders index, page 5)

should be:

http://domain.com/posts/6433 (show post 6433)

The page parameter can be discarded, it was used for comment pagination and is no longer needed. Both of these parameters are being passed to Rails as params[:page] and params[:postID] and going to the index action in the posts controller. I suppose some logic could be added in the controller (if :postID is present, then show correct post), but I think the correct way would be to use an nginx rewrite to reform the url, currently I am using:

```
rewrite "^/posts\?page=(.*)&postID=(.*)$" /posts/$2 break;
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect on the URL passed.

I'm looking for help in making the correct rewrite URL or in RoR routing would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this:

```
if ($arg_postID ~ "^([0-9]+)"){
  rewrite ^/(.*) /posts/$arg_postID? permanent;
}
```

It successfully turned

http://ihatethemarinecorps.com/posts?page=5&postID=8861

into

http://ihatethemarinecorps.com/posts/8861

Turns out nginx handles arguments (anything after ?) a bit differently than the rest of the URI. I could have accessed $arg_page in the rewrite as well, but had no need to. Let me know if you have a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` has special meaning in regular expressions -- it specifies that the expression before it (in this case the letter `s`) is expected to occur 0 or 1 times.

You'll need to escape the `?` using a `\`:

```
rewrite "^/posts\?page=(.*)&postID=(.*)$" /posts/$2 break;
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have known, and I think I tried it with escaping the ? before. I am using the command you wrote currently and I get the same result. Does the rewrite command need to be contained in a location or if block perhaps?